# Magento Product Custom option in New Order Email

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, downloadable, ce-1.9.2.2, order-email

I am trying to remove Html tags from (Downloadable) Product Custom Option values, but cannot yet figure out, from which file product custom options are fetched in New Order Email ?

I edited the following file but no luck:

```
app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

From which file product custom options are fetched in New Order Email ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to repost, but this answer on stackoverflow might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036507/list-item-options-in-magento-email-template/44887149#44887149

**EDIT**

In my case it looked like an observer was interfering with the `$this->getItemOptions()` method.

Try replacing the following block of code in

*app/design/frontend/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml*

```
<?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
<dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
    <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
    <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
        <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with this

```
    <?php if ($options = $_item->getProductOptions()): ?>
        <?php if (isset($options['options'])): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($options['options'] as $option): ?>
                <dt><strong><em><small><?php echo $option['label'] ?></small></em></strong></dt>
                <dd><?php echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value']))) ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (isset($options['additional_options'])): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($options['additional_options'] as $option): ?>
                <dt><strong><em><small><?php echo $option['label'] ?></small></em></strong></dt>
                <dd><?php echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value']))) ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (isset($options['attributes_info'])): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $option): ?>
                <dt><strong><em><small><?php echo $option['label'] ?></small></em></strong></dt>
                <dd><?php echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value']))) ?></dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100415)

Comment: cheers, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

front this file it fetching `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Item/Renderer/Default.php` line `67`

```
public function getItemOptions()
    {
        $result = array();
        if ($options = $this->getOrderItem()->getProductOptions()) {
            if (isset($options['options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['options']);
            }
            if (isset($options['additional_options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['additional_options']);
            }
            if (isset($options['attributes_info'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['attributes_info']);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: The correct class should be `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder`